# cmd window stops working, text file is read wrong with fstream

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

in the function Read() when i output arrays klas[] and nauj[] everything seems to be read fine, but back in the main function they get destroyed and seem to be filled with other text file. Do you have any idea whats the problem here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const char klase[] = "klase.txt";
const char naujokai[] = "lele.txt";

void Read(int klas[], int nauj[], int &nk, int &nj);

int main()
{
    int klas[] = {};
    int nauj[] = {};
    int nk;
    int nj;
    Read(klas, nauj, nk, nj);

    for(int i = 0; i < nk; i++){
        cout << klas[i] << endl;
    }for(int i = 0; i < nj; i++){
        cout << nauj[i] << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}

void Read(int klas[], int nauj[], int &nk, int &nj)
{
    ifstream fklase(klase);
    fklase >> nk;
    for(int i = 0;i < nk;i++){
        fklase >> klas[i];
        cout << klas[i] << endl << endl;
    }
    fklase.close();
    ifstream fnaujokai(naujokai);
    fnaujokai >> nj;
    for(int i = 0; i < nj; i++){
        fnaujokai >> nauj[i];
        cout << nauj[i] << endl << endl;
    }
    fnaujokai.close();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Zero-size arrays such as `int klas[] = {};` are not standard and writing into them as you do in `fklase >> klas[i];` is Undefined Behavior since they have no room to store anything. Also note that when you use `int klas[]` as a function argument it is actually equivalent to `int * klas`.

Comment: Hi, I changed both arrays so they have a maximum value like int klas[100] and its working! Thanks!